# Is it possible to start and build Rocket.Chat without ee directory(without enterprise code)?

Tags: rocket.chat

I'm playing with rocket.chat and trying to build my own custom CE build.

Now when I'm trying to start it locally `meteor npm start` it works fine, without any errors.

But after deleting '/ee' directory and `meteor npm start`:

> Error: Cannot find module '../ee/server/broker'
> ...
> => Exited with code: 1
> => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

From the release notes

> Also, it is worth mentioning that you are able to delete the entire EE repository if you wish to.

So the question is can I exclude enterpise code and run rocket.chat locally for development and later on make a custom build of Rocket.Chat CE.

Rocket.Chat@3.8.0-develop.
I haven't added new code yet.

Thanks in advance